# ASP.Net Core: Accessing application on IIS from subfolder without trailing slash resolves as document

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, iis, single-page-application

I'm using ASP.NET Core 3.1 application in combination with Angular 10. Application is deployed on IIS under `servername.com/test/customer1/app` . When I access this using trailing slash `servername.com/test/customer1/app/` application resolves correctly.

But when this trailing slash isn't present. `.../app` is resolved as a document (index.html) and redirect 301 with trailing slash isn't triggered to `.../app/` which causes other scripts to be loaded from `.../customer1/` folder which is incorrect.

I tried IIS url rewrite but no success.
I tried AppendTrailingSlash in Aspnet Core but no success.
I tried tinkering with base-href in index.html but no success.

Any kind of help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Update - here's whole startup.cs file:

```cs
public class Startup
{
    private IWebHostEnvironment _env { get; }
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }


    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        _env = env;
        Configuration = configuration;
    }


    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<PosContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:*****"]));

        services.AddDbContext<MxpContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:*****"]));

        // maybe this to resolve path on IIS with trailing slash - update - this doesn't work - ITS-1666
        // services.Configure<RouteOptions>(options => options.AppendTrailingSlash = true);

        // this is required for [FromBody] parse
        services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
        // string applicationUrl = Configuration["ApplicationUrl"].TrimEnd('/');

        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.SaveToken = true;
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ValidIssuer = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                    ValidAudience = Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
                };
            });

        // Add cors
        services.AddCors();

        services.AddControllersWithViews();

        // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist/browser";
        }); // without server-side rendering - if enabled, then reconfigure this here


        services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));

        // Configurations
        services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration);


        // Business Services
        services.AddScoped<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
    }


    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        EmailTemplates.Initialize(env);

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            // app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            // app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        // WPC-363
        app.UseExceptionHandler(a => a.Run(async context =>
        {
            IExceptionHandlerPathFeature exceptionHandlerPathFeature = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerPathFeature>();
            Exception exception = exceptionHandlerPathFeature.Error;

            string result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new {detail = exception.Message});
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            await context.Response.WriteAsync(result).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }));

        // app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        FileExtensionContentTypeProvider provider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
        provider.Mappings[".webmanifest"] = "application/manifest+json";
        StaticFileOptions staticFileOptions = new StaticFileOptions
        {
            ContentTypeProvider = provider
        };
        app.UseStaticFiles(staticFileOptions);
        if (!env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseSpaStaticFiles(staticFileOptions);
        }

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseCors(builder => builder
            .AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowAnyMethod());

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
            // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                // spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
                // spa.Options.StartupTimeout =
                //     TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120); // Increase the timeout if angular app is taking longer to startup
                spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer(
                    "http://localhost:4200"); // Use this instead to use the angular cli server
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And here's IIS folder structure:

```
D:
  test
    customer1
      app
        appsettings.json
        application.dll
        application.exe
        web.config
        wwwroot
        ClientApp
          dist
            browser
              index.html (and other angular things)
```

And index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>App</title>
    <!-- <base href="/"> NOTE THAT THIS IS COMMENTED OUT -->
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport" />
    <link href="favicon.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link href="manifest.webmanifest" rel="manifest" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/styles/fonts.css" >
    <meta content="#1976d2" name="theme-color" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.8ddc2f0d7150b199a6a0.css"></head>
  <body class="dx-viewport">
    <mxp-root></mxp-root>
  <script src="runtime-es2015.631761e0fea5972d5164.js" type="module"></script><script src="runtime-es5.631761e0fea5972d5164.js" nomodule defer></script><script src="polyfills-es5.c11c77f0f556bd2fcda5.js" nomodule defer></script><script src="polyfills-es2015.2584ae65025f22219d8d.js" type="module"></script><script src="main-es2015.38f4bd50fcbc94d695be.js" type="module"></script><script src="main-es5.38f4bd50fcbc94d695be.js" nomodule defer></script></body>
</html>
```

```
enter code here
```

Comment: Could you share your startup.cs content and the directory structure published on iis?

Comment: Hey @YongqingYu I updated description

Comment: Could you also provide your angluar root component?

Comment: Added also index.html. This should be all. Note the base-href not being used. This is fine as app works correctly without it. If I include it with for example <base href="/"> then it shows to servername.com instead of servername.com/test/customer1/app.